# Email validation in angular using reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to angular need your help. I am trying to validate a email using reactive form onkeyup event.

```js
 registerform:any;
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.registerform = new FormGroup({
        "emailId": new FormControl(null,[Validators.required,Validators.email])

      });
    }
    get emailid() { return this.registerform.get('emailId');}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="registerform" (ngSubmit) = "submitData()">
      <input type="text" formControlName="emailId" placeholder="email">
      <div *ngIf="emailid.invalid && (emailid.touched || emailid.dirty)">
        <span class="myerror" name="err" *ngIf="emailid.errors?.required">*Email is required.</span>
        <span class="myerror" name="err" *ngIf="emailid.errors?.email">*Email is not valid.</span>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: emailid.errors?.required... you have a typo in emailid.. it should be emailId

Comment: What issue you are facing?? can you please explain it bit more!

Comment: The email is not getting validated when the user is typing

Comment: On my side your program working fine! I test it with https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: You can also check from here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2kadks?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using from Validators you can create angular directive

```
@Directive({
selector: '[appEmailValidator]',
providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: EmailValidator, multi: true }
    ]
})

export class EmailValidator implements Validator {
    validator: ValidatorFn;
    constructor() {
        this.validator = validateEmailFactory();
    }
    validate(c: FormControl) {
        return this.validator(c);
    }
}



// validation function
function validateEmailFactory(): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: FormControl) => {
        if (c.value) {
            // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
            const isValidEmail = c.value.match(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/);
            const message = {
                emailCheck: {
                    message: 'Email address is invalid'
                }
            };
            return isValidEmail ? null : message;
        }
    };
}
```

Now use this directive in your input field

```
<input type="text" id="lpd-email-input" formControlName="email"
              class="form-control"
              [placeholder]="Email address" autocomplete="none" appEmailValidator/>
```